# Difference between MythX and Mythril for security auditing

Tags: security, mythril

I know that both mythrix and mythril are used for smart contracts auditing but I didn't figure out yet the difference between them. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both projects are created by the same team, and are used to analyze bytecode and locate weaknesses listed in the [SWC registry](https://swcregistry.io/). There are some notable differences:

- [Mythril](https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril) is a free and open-source smart contract security analyzer. It uses symbolic execution to detect a variety of security vulnerabilities. It runs on your local machine.
- [MythX](https://mythx.io/) is a cloud-based smart contract security service. It performs security analysis remotely, accepting jobs and returning results via an API. A free version is available, but for a complete analysis you must sign up and purchase a subscription.

The MythX API has been integrated into many development frameworks, including [Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests-security-analysis.html), [Truffle](https://docs.mythx.io/en/latest/tools/truffle/index.html) and [Remix](https://docs.mythx.io/en/latest/tools/remix/index.html). Submitting a job is a fairly straightforward process.

You can learn more about the differences from this official blog post: [MythX Tech: Behind the Scenes of Smart Contract Security Analysis](https://blog.mythx.io/features/mythx-tech-behind-the-scenes-of-smart-contract-analysis/)

Comment: Obligatory disclaimer: I am the lead developer of Brownie. I do not receive any financial compensation from MythX.